# Python socket error: An object that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

Here I am confused to initialize the socket when the instance is initialized, and I use it to transfer data through it in a loop.

```
class Server2:
    host = "localhost"
    port = 44444
    s = ""
    sock = ""
    addr = ""


    def __init__(self,voitingSistem,voitingInterfece,voiting,sql):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.listen(5)
        self.sock, self.addr =self.s.accept()
        self.client = WorkWithClient()
        self.voitingSistem = voitingSistem()
        self.voitingInterfece = voitingInterfece()
        self.voiting = Voiting("d")
        super().__init__()

     def mainLoop(self):
         while True:
             buf = self.sock.recv(1024) # receive and decode a command
             print("getting command: "+(buf.decode('utf8')))
             ansver = self.client.AcceptCommand(buf.decode('utf8')) # act upon the command

             if buf.decode('utf8') == "exit":
                 self.sock.send("bye")
                 break
             elif buf:
                 self.sock.send(buf)
                 print(buf.decode('utf8'))
                 self.sock.close()
```

Error:

> An attempt was made to perform an operation on an object that is not a socket

Comment: Which line did this happen?

Comment: The program receives the first data. But the next bit of data crashes with such a mistake.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly in the paste.  (4 spaces missing before mainLoop). Also it will take the whole stacktrace to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition is always true and the code will always be executed unless `buf` is equal to `exit`:

```
elif buf:
    self.sock.send(buf)
    print(buf.decode('utf8'))
    self.sock.close()
```

Earlier in the code you obtain `buf` by calling `self.sock.recv(1024)`. For a usual socket in blocking mode it will return at least one byte. There are no circumstances under which `buf` will be empty. Program execution will be simply blocked until some data arrives. If something really bad happens, like disconnect, you'll be notified by an exception, not by receiving an empty buffer.

So essentially you close a connection to a client after the first chunk of data is received. I believe you meant to have `self.sock.close()` in `== 'exit'` section.